# Geometry nodes, How to set the positions of an arc?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to set three points of an arc to the positions of three vertices but I cant seem to figure out how. I take the position of a point of index 1,2 and 3 and set the arc on those points but I don't know why the vector wont let me do that.

[image: Node group in question]

Comment: You might want to indicate that you're using 3.1 beta or 3.2 alpha; which are not yet released.

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.1. But I cant make it work in 3.0.1 eighter with a 3 point circle instead of an arc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the transfer node but do it like this

[image: How to use the position of a vertex as a control]

The technique, repeated 3 times here, is to use the *Transfer Attribute* Node, set to *Vector*, *Index*, and *Point* to extract the position of the first three vertices from the original geometry.

Here is an example using a triangle as the input geometry:

[image: Sample of the nodes at work]

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats it. I also found a solution with attribute statistics, the autput is a circle there also. I guess your solution is more elegant.

Comment: How do you make these explanatory gifs? Is that a function in Blender?

Comment: @RoelDeden I use a program called [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) because animated Gifs are one of the few 'video' formats that stackexchange supports.  It seems to be the most popular among Windows users.  I'm not sure I'd call my solution more elegant but it does generalize a bit better than using attribute statistics, I think.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a restriction of geometry nodes. You cannot plug a "diamond socket" into a "round socket".

The diamond sockets represent multiple values (like e.g. all points, all vertices) the round values represent only one value.

What you can do is, e.g. use empties which create your arc like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

if you really want to do this with 3 vertices, you have to calculate the arc "on your own", so search for that formula in the internet and calculate your points for that.